# Why does the "." get not caught in the regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to have a regular epxresion, that allows that checks wether the email adress given is correct. Firstly, it will check if a specific provider is there, in this case (`@test.de`) - this is not the problem. However the email names that are allowed must consist only of letters or dots. so: `.@test.de` is valid. However this specific case does not get accepted. My regex looks like the following:

```
[A-Za-z\.]{1,}\b@test\.de\b
```

It works fine, for all other cases but if a "`.`" is only in front of the `@`it does not fit.

Any pointers what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Remove the first `\b`

Comment: `\b` only matches if it is preceded by a non-word-character and *followed* by a word-character. `@` is *not* a word-character, hence `\b@` can never match.

Comment: Thank you both, I did not know that

Comment: Actually, `\.\b@` will never match, not just `\b@`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: Ugh, of course, it goes both ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first word boundary `\b` in your pattern requires that there must be a word char before `@`. Thus, a dot cannot appear there, the match is failed.

You need to remove the word boundary, use

```
[A-Za-z.]+@test\.de\b
```

Note you do not need to escape a dot inside a character class, it already denotes a literal dot.

If you still want to match "whole" words after removing `\b`, you might use lookbehinds (if the regex engine supports them):

```
(?<!\w)[A-Za-z.]+@test\.de\b
```

or to only match after whitespace/start of string:

```
(?<!\S)[A-Za-z.]+@test\.de\b
```

Or just use a word boundary if the name starts with a letter, and a non-word boundary if it starts with a dot:

```
(?:\b[A-Za-z]|\B\.)[A-Za-z.]*@test\.de\b
```

See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/P6dKlm/2)

Comment: Actually, a lot depends on the context where the strings you need to match appear. `\b` is context dependent, and in most situations should be used with care.